# Redux build index of object

Tags: design-patterns, redux, react-redux, flux

In a redux app lets say its a blog.
State can look like

```
{
  Posts: {
    1:{day:'2016-03-13', id:1},
    2:{day:'2016-03-14',id:2},
    .....
  }
}
```

Now in a certain component I want to show all posts of a specific day, I can filter all posts using Array.filter to get posts of this day, but this mean that if I have 1000's of post every time component refresh it will recalculate whole filter.

So in such circumstances I think its better if I had an index in redux store something like

```
{
  PostsByDate: {
    '2017-03-13': [1,2], .. Etc
  }
}
```

So how to build such index and make sure that its always in sync with posts object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you´re having a lot of data (+1000 blog posts) stored in the client side you might think about pagination and running the filter on the server side. The computational cost of the filter should be low, but it really depends on the type of filter you use, if you´re filtering using the body of every blog post most likely you´ll have performance issues. But if the cost of filtering is low, the cost of joining the array of ids with the complete collection of posts might be very similar, so there should´t be a significant performance gain with the architecture you´re proposing.

That being said, I would do it by having inside an array the collection of post ids to show, and updating that array every time any filter changes. If there is no filter then the array is `undefined` and you show all the posts.

**action creator**

```
function filterPosts(filter) {
  return { type: "FILTER_POSTS", filter };
}
```

**reducer**

```
switch (action.type) {
  ...
  case "FILTER_POSTS":
    return { 
      ...state, 
      PostsFiltered: action.filter 
        ? Posts.filter(action.filter).map(p => p.id)
        : undefined 
    };
  ...
}
```

**container**

```
container = connect(
  state => ({ ... }), 
  dispatch => bindActionCreators({
    onFilter: filterPosts,
    onRemoveFilter: filterPosts.bind(null, undefined)
  }, dispatch)
)(Component);
```

**component**

```
filter() {
  // Use whatever filter you want here
  this.props.onFilter(...);
}
removeFilter() {
  this.props.onRemoveFilter();
}
render() {
  ...
    {
      this.props.postsFiltered 
        ? this.props.posts.filter(p => this.props.postsFiltered.contains(p.id))
        : this.props.posts
    }
  ...
}
```

Don't struggle with collections, use [Immutable](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjA7rrkl5rTAhVIE5AKHenZDacQFghEMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.github.io%2Fimmutable-js%2F&usg=AFQjCNFoOUtwcPdnwyqePJIWTUD29vpMNg&sig2=Sxo473c7OKP7XUNdFOa_2w)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is recommended in official redux docs is building indices for your data. My minimal structure for collection state is

```
Map({
  byId: Map(),
  allIds: List([])
})
```

where `byId` map is basically what you have in your `Posts` hash. Think of your redux store as a client-side database, this mode of thought really helps if you have at least some backend experience IMO. Querying map by key is O(1) operation, so this gives you really fast fetches by id (think `SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE id = your_id LIMIT 1`).

Now, allIds is just a list of all ids which are keys in `byId` and is useful when you are displaying list of data - list component has just list of ids and pass each individual id to child `ListItem` components, which are also connected to redux store and grab individual items in their `mapStateToProps` function using simple selector: `selectPost(state, postId) { return state.posts.getIn(['byId', postId]) }`.

This gives you huge performance gains, especially if `PostsList` component uses re-select function to cache fetching list of ids, since if you reorder collection, React handles it the smart way using `key` prop, which should be post id in your case - so rerender is very fast. also if some post changes, only this individual post component needs to be rerendered.

You can take this approach bit further by introducing extra indices for your specific use-cases: if you want to show all posts by some user, you can add `byUserId: Map(<lists of post ids>)` for faster lookup in this case. Exactly like relational database index, it's same concept.

In rails every model has updated_at timestamp field, so simple caching could check for latest updated_at for fetched collection on backend and compare that with header, which your client can send with all api requests, if it's note later than client value then client data is not stale and backend can respond with corresponding header instantly, it's like 2-5 ms for response, and then client can completely bypass fetching json, parsing it and feeding to reducer function, so lots of performance gains on client too. This way your components can just fire api requests on componentDidMount without any complex logic and caching layer will handle the rest

Comment: Also, you should totally use immutable.js for fast and sane collections. All my models are basically immutable.js Records, and working with collections is heaven compared to native javascript collections. immutability really helps with performance here, also. See React.PureComponent and mapStateToProps docs on how redux implements shouldComponentUpdate for connected components.
Also, pagination is essential, plus some kind of http caching in your backend + simple caching mechanism on client to bypass all those api calls helps a lot